# Live video production on PC? With VLC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-capture

I realize VLC is the swiss army knife of multimedia and video, but I have a tricky problem that may or may not be solved by it.

Suppose I want to overlay video (or an image) over video from a capture card, and then send the output to a secondary graphics card in real time.  Is this possible with VLC?  Think graphic overlays for TV production, but for putting up on projector screens during an event.

[image: Lower-third test shot]

I also wouldn't be opposed to using something other than VLC for this, but whatever I use must support a wide variety of video formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is video mixing software to do this, [NeuroMixer](http://www.neuromixer.com/) might be what you're looking for.